# CURL CURLOPT_URL is causing php script to run twice

Tags: php, curl

I've a curl script that looks like this:

```
<?php

echo "hello";

$download_file = "http://www.myremotesite.com/api/download.php?autoupdate=1";

$temp_file = tempnam('/tmp','TEMP');

$ch2 = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL,            $download_file);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER,         FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,    FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10000); 

$file = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);

$fp = fopen($temp_file, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $file);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

The problem is that the output on the page after execution looks like this:

```
hellohello
```

And from my testing I've narrowed it down to the $download_file URL. If I change that to , say, http://www.google.com, there is no issue.

Any idea on what my be causing this double output? It's happening in other situations too for different URLs. I really think it's something server based because this same setup works fine on other hosts.

***Server Information***
Linux x-mirrors.com 2.6.26-2-openvz-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 25 06:04:33 UTC 2011 x86_64
PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny10 
Fast CGI Enabled

Comment: I feel like we're missing code here. Where's `$ch1`?

Comment: Nothing in that script would cause it to run twice, unless it was requested twice.

Comment: @ceejayoz it was there when I was seeing if the issue could be narrowed down to two CURL requests running in one script... you know just theory testing. $ch2 is what remained by the time I figured out what was causing it to print hello twice. 

Hey Marc, 
I agree. Nevertheless....

Comment: how are you executing the script?

Comment: Hey Phill, at the moment, this script above is the code for a test.php, which I am running in a browser.

Comment: did you solve this issue ?

Comment: I don't remember what it was over. I have since moved on so I imagine it's solved. I don't remember what the problem was. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. it's because of .htaccess file probably . if you use

```
   RewriteEngine On  
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

. check it without them.